# Merge multiple categorical variables into one using value from another value in r

Tags: r

I have data columns like:

```
Weather1    Weather.2   Weather3        
Sunny       Sunny       NA              
Cloudy      NA          some cloud      
Hazy        Hazy        Hazy            
Warm        NA          Warm            
NA          NA          NA
```

Here is a snippet of code to recreate the data:

```
example = data.frame(Weather1 = c('Sunny','Cloudy','Hazy','Warm','NA'),
                     Weather.2 = c('Sunny','NA','Hazy','NA','NA'),
                     Weather3 = c('NA','some cloud','Hazy','NA', 'NA'))
```

I want to combine the three variables like the following:

```
Weather1    Weather.2   Weather3        combine_weather
Sunny       Sunny       NA              Sunny
Cloudy      NA          some cloud      Cloudy
Hazy        Hazy        Hazy            Hazy
Warm        NA          NA              Warm
NA          NA          NA              NA
```

I want to use value from first variable if there is any mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce` to fill in `NA` horizontally with the first non-missing value.

Note I have changed your string "NA" into real `NA` first.

There are a few ways to specify columns in "tidy-select" style:

1. If your columns that need to be acted on all start with the string "Weather", you can do `select(., starts_with("Weather"))`.
2. If they are ordered next to each other, you can do `select(., Weather1:Weather3)`.
3. Or select them manually `select(., Weather1, Weather.2, Weather3)`

```
library(dplyr)

example %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(.x == "NA", NA, .x)),
                   combine_weather = coalesce(!!!select(., everything())))

  Weather1 Weather.2   Weather3 combine_weather
1    Sunny     Sunny       <NA>           Sunny
2   Cloudy      <NA> some cloud          Cloudy
3     Hazy      Hazy       Hazy            Hazy
4     Warm      <NA>       <NA>            Warm
5     <NA>      <NA>       <NA>              NA
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can mention the variables explicitly? I have other variables in my actual dataset and want to avoid any conflicts.

Comment: @PrajwalManiPradhan You can replace `everything()` in `coalesce` with your column names in tidy-select style

Comment: Sorry, a noob here. Can you please show how?

Comment: @PrajwalManiPradhan See my update :)

Comment: I updated as follows: combine_weather = coalesce(!!!select(., select(., Weather1, Weather.2, Weather3))). It gives me error in local_error_context... I must be making some error.

Comment: @PrajwalManiPradhan You only need one `select`

Comment: This still gives error: combine_weather = coalesce(select(., Weather1, Weather.2, Weather3))). Can you please share the exact modification as a comment? Sorry for the multiple requests.

Comment: @PrajwalManiPradhan Try `combine_weather = coalesce(!!!select(., Weather1, Weather.2, Weather3))`

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be first define how your `combine_weather` could be in pattern:
then `extract` after `unite`:

```
library(tidyverse)

pattern <- c("Sunny|Cloudy|Hazy|Warm")

example %>% 
  na_if("NA") %>% 
  unite(combine_weather, starts_with("Weather"), sep = " ", na.rm = TRUE,  remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(combine_weather = str_extract(combine_weather, pattern))
```

```
  combine_weather Weather1 Weather.2   Weather3
1           Sunny    Sunny     Sunny       <NA>
2          Cloudy   Cloudy      <NA> some cloud
3            Hazy     Hazy      Hazy       Hazy
4            Warm     Warm      <NA>       <NA>
5            <NA>     <NA>      <NA>       <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(example)[
  , combined.weather:=fcoalesce(.SD)
  , .SDcols=c('Weather1', 'Weather.2', 'Weather3')]

example
##    Weather1 Weather.2   Weather3 combined.weather
## 1:    Sunny     Sunny       <NA>            Sunny
## 2:   Cloudy      <NA> some cloud           Cloudy
## 3:     Hazy      Hazy       Hazy             Hazy
## 4:     Warm      <NA>       <NA>             Warm
## 5:     <NA>      <NA>       <NA>             <NA>
```